# How to utilize Pageable when running a custom delete query in Spring JPA for mongodb?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am working on creating a tool allowing admins to purge data from the database. Our one collection has millions of records making deletes seize up the system. Originally I was just running a query with that returns a Page and dropping that into the standard delete. Ideally i'd prefer to run the query and delete in one go.

```
@Query(value = "{ 'timestamp' : {$gte : ?0, $lte: ?1 }}")
public Page deleteByTimestampBetween(Date from, Date to, Pageable pageable);
```

Is this possible, using the above code the system behaves the same where the program doesnt continue the delete function and the data isnt removed from mongo. Or is there a better approach?

Comment: are you looking for ways to perform batch delete ?

Comment: yes between two dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible using Pageable/Query annotation. You can use Bulk Write to process deletes in batches.

Something like

```
int count = 0;
int batch = 100; //Send 100 requests at a time
BulkOperations bulkOps = mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, YourPojo.class);
List<DateRange> dateRanges = generateDateRanges(from, to, step); //Add a function to generate date ranges with the defined step.

for (DateRange dateRange: dateRanges){
    Query query = new Query();
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("timestamp").gte(dateRange.from), Criteria.where("timestamp").lte(dateRange.to));
    query.addCriteria(criteria);
    bulkOps.remove(query);
    count++;
    if (count == batch) {
        bulkOps.execute();
        count = 0;
    }
}

if (count > 0) {
    bulkOps.execute();
}
```

Comment: is this better than just querying and looping through a pageable object in batches and deleting that way?

Comment: This is using bulk api - all the actions are performed on the mongodb side in batches and possibly run in parallel. so there is no need to query and remove in two operations. Both operations are done all at once on the mongodb server side.